# react-select can load async data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a select component using `react-select` plugin.

In the process of implementing this project, I have some kind of tricky problem with that. Check out my source code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j148r99695

1. The problem that I have is I want to fetch all genresList data from the server and mapping them to select component. But somehow or I do wrong something, It's not working. Please see source code above to help me.
2. I fetch data from `Movies` component. Its work well and I pass a props to `FormFilter` component: `<FormFilter genresList={this.state.genres} />`. And in the `FormFilter` component, I check `this.props.genresList`, it's available. But when I'm trying to assign it to `FormFilter` state and `console.log("state", this.state.genres);` that. It's empty. Anyone can tell me why?
3. Default `react-select` using `value` and `label` to display data to select component. But you know some cases we have to custom that. I try it out by using map to transform to other arrays. But It's the best way? How can I custom `valueKey` and `labelKey`.

I'm using `react-select` beta version2.

UPDATE: I was fixed my project. Please check out the link below. Somehow it's not working. I was commend inside source code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/moym59w39p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make it works I have changed the FormFilter.js implementation:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as Animated from "react-select/lib/animated";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/lib/Async";

class FormFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: "",
      selectedOption: "",
      genres: []
    };
  }

  selectGenreHandleChange = newValue => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, "");
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    console.log(inputValue);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.genresOption();
  }

  filterGenres = inputValue => {
    const genres = this.genresOption();
    //HERE - return the filter
    return genres.filter(genre =>
      genre.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  };

  promiseOptions = inputValue => {
    return new Promise(resolve => { // HERE - you have to return the promise
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(this.filterGenres(inputValue));
      }, 1000);
    });
  };

  genresOption() {
    const options = [];
    const genres = this.props.genresList.genres; //HERE - array is genres in genresList
        if (genres && genres instanceof Array) {
          genres.map(genre => options.push({ value: genre.id, label: genre.name}));
        }
    return options;
  }

  render() {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;

    if (this.state.genres) console.log("state", this.state.genres);

    if (this.props.genresList)
      console.log("Movies props", this.props.genresList);

    return (
      <div className="filter_form">
        <span className="search_element full">
          <label htmlFor="genres">Genres</label>
          <AsyncSelect
            className="select genres"
            classNamePrefix="tmdb_select"
            isMulti
            isSearchable="true"
            isClearable="true"
            cacheOptions
            components={Animated}
            value={inputValue}
            defaultOptions
            onInputChange={this.selectGenreHandleChange}
            loadOptions={this.promiseOptions}
          />
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormFilter;
```

I have write a comment "HERE - something" to let you know what I changed. There are not big problems :)

Comment: To customize labelKey you can pass to react-select the prop labelKey = {".."} with the label you prefer and you can use even valueKey = {".."} with the value property you prefer.

Say your array has objects like {prop1:28, prop2:"Action"} you will specify that valueKey = {"prop1"} and labelKey = {"prop2"}

Comment: Thank guy, Paolo. But after 1 hour, I found that we don't need to use `AsyncSelect` component because I was fetched data and set it to state, it's always available. Only using `Select` it's fine. But i don't know why data cannot be rendered. Please check this source code url: https://codesandbox.io/s/moym59w39p I was fixed. But its not work. In `FormFilter` component. => I was commend in there

Comment: @PhuongThuan In your fetchGenresList function the setState should be inside the  "then" https://codesandbox.io/s/lx0kl8p49m 

Please pay attention :)

Comment: OMG, Thank u so much. It's working. I really didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

I did some changed in your [FIDDLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/myqz2r0668) and it's works for me

Something like

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Movies from './Movies';

import "./styles.css";

class App  extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Movies />
    </div>
  );
}
}

let a = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, a);
```

Comment: thank guy. But after 1 hour, I found that we don't need to use `AsyncSelect` component because I was fetched data and set it to state, it's always available. Only using `Select` it's fine. But i don't know why data cannot be rendered. Please check this source code url: https://codesandbox.io/s/moym59w39p    I was fixed. But its not work. In `FormFilter` component. => I was commend in there.

Comment: @PhuongThuan, You have to updates your movies data in `genres` in `Promise` . 
I changed it in [FIDDLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/r09n560j7q)

```fetchGenresList() {
    const options = [];
    requestApi.fetchGenres("movie").then(response => {
      var genres = response.data.genres;
      if (genres) {
        genres.map(genre =>
          options.push({ label: genre.name, value: genre.id })
        );
      }
      this.setState({ genres: options });
    });
    //this.setState({ genres: options });
  }```

Comment: Thank @Chintan, But why I was set `defaultValue` in `Select` but it's not working ?? In Year select, Sort by select and also Genre. Can you tell me why?